# is this answer rude?

Tags: offensive-language, politeness

recently some on in LinkedIn send a message to me:

*Thank you for connecting with me! I am recruiting for an Android Developer role (multiple levels) for a company whose product mostly likely impacts you every time you go out to eat. Come be part of a team making technology for seamless customer experiences for millions of people.

.

.

.

Warm Regards,

.

.

.*

and I answer him like this:

*Hi _,
thanks for informing me about this position.

and yes I'm interested and I want to know more.*

but I did not hear from him back. is there anything wrong or rude in my answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not an English language question.

Comment: It's **seamless** not "seemless", BTW.  Your typo or theirs?

Comment: Rather than "I'm interested and I want to know more", were it me I would have written "I would be interested in learning more about it". "I want to know more" is not rude or impolite, but just comes across as slightly demanding.

Comment: Your answer was not rude or impolite, but you said nothing that could make you stand out among the other people to whom this message may have been sent.  Or, do you think that they were specifically targeting you?  It is always good to say something substantive in a situation like this, providing of course that you have a clue as to what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is not rude or impolite.